# How do I cast generic T to f32 if I know that it's possible?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a generic `struct` with one field, that can only be `i32` or `f32`.

```
trait MyInt {
    fn blank();
}

impl MyInt for i32 {
    fn blank() {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl MyInt for f32 {
    fn blank() {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

struct MyStruct<T> where T: MyInt {
    field: T
}

impl<T> MyStruct<T> where T: MyInt {
    fn new(var: T) -> MyStruct<T> {
        MyStruct {
            field: var
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a method which returns field value `as f32`, whether it's `i32` or `f32`. I know that this cast should always be possible since field types are limited to two mentioned above, but how do I go about it? Apparently `as` only works on primitive types and I tried going the `From` route, but I am doing something wrong, this doesn't work.

```
fn to_f32(&self) -> f32 where T: From<i32> {
        f32::from(self.field);
}
```

Comment: You do realize that a number of `i32` values cannot be represented (exactly) as a `f32` because by IEEE standard `f32` only has a 23 bits mantissa (so it could represent an hypothetical `i24` but no more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, `as` only works with concrete types.

Using the `From` or `Into` trait for the conversion is a good approach, but these are not implemented for a i32 -> f32 conversion. The reason is most likely that it's a potentially lossy conversion as Matthieu M. says.

You'll have to work with `f64` instead of `f32`.

I would suggest changing the trait to this:

```
trait MyInt: Copy + Into<f64> {
    fn blank();
}
```

Then you can add the method to do the conversion:

```
fn to_f64(&self) -> f64 {
    self.field.into()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Can you explain what this line `trait MyInt: Copy + Into<f64>` means? Types implementing `MyInt` trait also should  have `Copy` and `Into` traits implemented?

Comment: @ehsisthatsweird: yes, the portion after the `:` spells out the requirement that a type has to fulfill for `MyInt` to be implementable; it also means that when using a type that implements `MyInt` you know it necessarily implements those other traits.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add the cast as a method to your `MyInt` trait:

```
trait MyInt {
    fn to_f32_lossy(self) -> f32;
}

impl MyInt for i32 {
    fn to_f32_lossy(self) -> f32 {
        self as f32
    }
}

impl MyInt for f32 {
    fn to_f32_lossy(self) -> f32 {
        self
    }
}
```