# How to convert generic primitive types in Rust?

Tags: generics, casting, rust

I would like to write something like the following:

```
pub struct Point<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
}

impl<T> Point<T> {
    pub fn from<U>(other: Point<U>) -> Point<T> {
        Point {
            x: other.x as T,
            y: other as T,
        }
    }
}
```

This is not possible:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `U` as `T`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:16
  |
9 |             x: other.x as T,
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types. Consider using the `From` trait
```

Looking at [How do I cast generic T to f32 if I know that it's possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766261/how-do-i-cast-generic-t-to-f32-if-i-know-that-its-possible), I learnt that the `From` trait doesn't work for `i32` to `f32` conversion, which is what I wanted originally.

The simplest solution I can come up with is to write a function like:

```rust
pub fn float2_from_int2(v: Point<i32>) -> Point<f32> {
   Point::<f32>::new(v.x as f32, v.y as f32)
}
```

Clearly Rust has no problem casting from `i32` to `f32`. Is there a nicer way to write this?

Comment: Note that you should take `self`, that make more sense

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I don't have a `self` yet, because I just was about to create the `Point<T>`. Hence the `from<U>`, as a constructor so to speak.

Comment: I not advice you to implement `From` there is a reason where there is no `From<i32> for f32` implementation, maybe do this, https://play.integer32.com/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6aea7192ed830c36aa2a53c31f219ff1, but be aware that like my exemple show, this could lead to strange behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [ToPrimitive](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/trait.ToPrimitive.html) trait from [num](https://crates.io/crates/num)
example (you can avoid Option with AsPrimitive):

```rust
pub struct Point<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
}

impl<T: Copy + 'static> Point<T> {
    pub fn from<U: num::cast::AsPrimitive<T>>(other: Point<U>) -> Point<T> {
        Point {
            x: other.x.as_(),
            y: other.y.as_(),
        }
    }
}

fn do_stuff() {
    let a = Point{x: 0i32, y: 0i32};
    let b = Point::<f32>::from(a);
}
```

Comment: The methods in traits `NumCast` and `ToPrimitive` return an `Option` because it is possible that the given value cannot be represented in the target type (e.g. you cannot hold `256` in a `u8`). These are indeed safer to use, since they can avoid odd situations. `AsPrimitive` disregards this, thus behaving exactly like the `as` operator.

Comment: Maybe implementing the newly stabilized `TryFrom` trait would be a good way to handle the `Optional` results?

Comment: How could one implement this in / as a "From" trait? Like:
impl<T, U> From<Point<T>> for Point<U>...