# Convert T into f32 when T is required to have implemented Into<f32>

Tags: rust

So I have the following snippet of code where I want to accept a `Vec`of arbitrary values and cast those values into f32. This is to work with floats, ints, unsigned values, etc.

```rust
pub struct Vals {
    // Our concrete values
    mat: Vec<Vec<f32>>,
    shape: (usize, usize),
    name: String,
}

impl Vals {
    pub fn from_vec<T: Into<f32>>(vec: Vec<T>, name: Option<String>) -> Self {
        let s1 = vec.iter().len();
        let mut as_mat: Vec<Vec<f32>> = Vec::new();

        let recasted = vec.iter().map(|&x| x as f32).collect(); 

        as_mat.push(vec);

        Vals {
            mat: as_mat,
            shape: (s1, 1),
            name: name.unwrap_or(String::from("")),
        }
    }
```

I'm running into an issue on the following line:

`let recasted = vec.iter().map(|&x| x as f32).collect();` where it is telling me `an` as `expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object`, but I thought that my specifying the `Into` trait would have handled that issue?

I've read through the [From and Into Rust Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html), but nothing there seems to help me address my issue. I see that it mentions `how to create itself from another type, hence providing a very simple mechanism for converting between several types` but I would have thought I could handle this. I'm mostly looking for advice on either restructuring my code to make it possible, or directly addressing the bug.

Thank you!

---

Edit: I've restructured the `from_vec` function with the recommendation from @drewtato and now have

```
    pub fn from_vec<T: Into<f32>>(vec: Vec<T>, name: Option<String>) -> Self {
        // `Vec` has a `len` method already
        let s1 = vec.len();
        let recasted = vec.into_iter().map(|x| x.into()).collect();
        // Don't need to create the empty `Vec`
        let mat = vec![recasted];

        Vals {
            mat,
            shape: (s1, 1),
            name: name.unwrap_or_default(),
        }
    }
```

but in my test case I've got

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn test_vec(){
        let v1= vec![1,2,3];
        let res = Vals::from_vec(v1, None);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working the way I intend. I'm getting

```rust
the trait bound `f32: std::convert::From<i32>` is not satisfied
[E0277] the trait `std::convert::From<i32>` is not implemented for 
`f32` Help: the following other types implement trait 
`std::convert::From<T>`: <f32 as std::convert::From<bool>> <f32 as 
std::convert::From<i16>> <f32 as std::convert::From<i8>> <f32 as 
std::convert::From<u16>> <f32 as std::convert::From<u8>> Note: 
required for `i32` to implement `std::convert::Into<f32>` Note: 
required for `f32` to implement `std::convert::TryFrom<i32>`
```

which I don't understand. I'm reading this as the cast is not implemented, but if I were to implement the cast wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the generic?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55867367/5397009

Comment: and also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35766805/5397009

Comment: @IanQ ordinarily I'd roll back your edits since they invalidate some answers and that's not allowed for edits, bit I can't since that now would invalidate drewtatos answer, in the future please create a new question and link to the old one if applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` is a special builtin that can convert primitives and a few other things, but it's not connected to any trait, so you can't use it on generics. This is unlike nearly all other operators, which *are* connected to a trait. `+` corresponds to the `std::ops::Add` trait, `*` is the `std::ops::Deref` trait, and even `for` loops use the `std::iter::IntoIterator` trait.

`Into` is a totally normal trait, not connected to any operator syntax. Being a trait, you can use it to restrict generics, which you've done, and then use its methods on generic values. But it does not know about `as` at all.

In order to use your `T: Into`, you need to use `Into::into`:

```rs
let recasted = vec.into_iter().map(|x| x.into()).collect();
```

If you want to be able to take any value that can be converted with `as`, you can use the num-traits crate, which provides the [`AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) trait. That trait still doesn't know what `as` is, but they have a method `as_` which has been implemented for every possible conversion to call `as` internally. `x.as_()` is roughly equivalent to `x as _`.

```rs
use num_traits::AsPrimitive;

impl Vals {
    pub fn from_vec<T: AsPrimitive<f32>>(vec: Vec<T>, name: Option<String>) -> Self {
    ...
        let recasted = vec.into_iter().map(|x| x.as_()).collect();
    ...
    }
}
```

This is slightly different from `Into`, since you can convert from `f64` to `f32` with `as` but not `Into`, and types outside the standard library may implement `Into<f32>` but would rarely implement `AsPrimitive`.

---

Your other error is because `Into::into` takes ownership of the value it's converting. For types that implement `Copy`, like the number primitives, you can just dereference them to get an owned value. You can make that work in your function by further restricting the generic.

```rs
pub fn from_vec<T: Into<f32> + Copy>
```

Note that if you do that, you should [take your parameter by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/6274355).

```rs
(vec: &[T], name: Option<String>)
```

The other option is that if you want to be able to accept values that are not `Copy`, you can use `into_iter` to have owned values all the way through. I used that in the first snippet, and here it is again.

```rs
let recasted = vec.into_iter().map(|x| x.into()).collect();
```

However, this restricts you into taking ownership of `Vec`, and can't use `&[T]` in its place.

There's some more changes you can make that are direct equivalents. Here's the whole function cleaned up.

```rs
pub fn from_vec<T: Into<f32>>(vec: Vec<T>, name: Option<String>) -> Self {
    // `Vec` has a `len` method already
    let s1 = vec.len();
    let recasted = vec.into_iter().map(|x| x.into()).collect();
    // Don't need to create the empty `Vec`
    let mat = vec![recasted];

    Vals {
        // This is the same as `mat: mat,`
        mat,
        shape: (s1, 1),
        // The default of `String` is an empty string
        name: name.unwrap_or_default(),
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, than you for your answer! That was quite enlightening. As a follow up, I've updated my question. Would you be able to take a look at the bottom and give me an idea of how to move forward?

Comment: Thank you so much! One last thing - I added an edit to my question, but TL;DR the tests don't seem to want to work with the code you have posted. Could you share your insight?

Comment: The one with `&[T]`? You would need to call it like `from_vec(&vec, None)` or `from_vec(vec.as_slice(), None)` instead of `from_vec(vec, None)`. @IanQ

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a `&[T]`. I'm referring to the most snippet you had pasted.

Comment: I have no idea then. It's likely that the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `into` to convert your values into `f32`

```rust
let recasted: Vec<f32> = vec.into_iter().map(|x| x.into()).collect();
```